# Drupal 8 - Results of a page excluding a block results

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

I have a "Groups" entity that has some data (title, members, outstanding publications, etc.).
In addition I have another entity "Publications" by title and details.

In each "group" I have a field "entity reference" to highlight 10 publications in each group.

I have a page that lists all publications of a group.

On this page showing all the publications of a group and I need to show all publications LESS those 10 publications marked as "important".

How can you do that?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you using Views module for that query?

Comment: Do not.

For these views I am using page filters.

The leading publications are the field itself.

And on the page "all publications" are the ones on the page filtered by the group ID (introduced as "contextual filter")